# Would "Glue them to each other." be as idiomatic as "Glue them together."?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I have heard a native english speaker, who was showing how to make things from paper, said this:

**"Glue them together".** (There were two pieces of paper, and she put some glue on one of them, and sticked it to the other piece of paper, when she said this.)

As a non-native speaker, I would not imagine saying it that way and would probably say:

**"Glue them to each other."**

Would mine be unidiomatic?

Comment: No, *Glue them to each other* isn't very idiomatic. You either glue ***one*** thing ***to*** another, or you glue (two or more) things ***together***. Here's [the usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Glue+them+together%2CGlue+them+to+each+other&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) to prove it (see where it says *Ngrams not found: **Glue them to each other***).

Comment: ...also note that the past tense of ***to stick*** in the sense of "glue, attach, adhere", is ***stuck***, not ***sticked***.

Comment: It's the same with other verbs (tie, stick) and without "them". I wouldn't think "to each other" is bad, but it's certainly much less common.

Comment: "Glue them to each other" is not unidiomatic, just not as common as "glue them together".  https://www.nano-reef.com/forums/topic/51692-glue-and-rocks/  or https://woodweb.com/knowledge_base/Gluing_Solid_Wood_Edging.html  or https://faeriefashion.livejournal.com/1133936.html or https://www.woodworkingtalk.com/threads/help-table-seams-coming-apart.29570/

Comment: Let's make these answers *answers*.

Answer (score 1):

Generally idiomatically interchangeable, though "glue them to each other" would tend to refer to gluing only two things together, whereas "glue them together" could refer to any number.  But that's likely regionally variable as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Glue them together** is the correct way to say it. I've never heard of the other usage.